# CircleCI mongo executor failed

Tags: circleci, circleci-orb

I used the new Circle v2.1 format, and declare an executor using the latest OpenJDK and mongo, but the mongo container always failed when running the pipeline.

```yaml
version: 2.1

orbs:
  maven: circleci/maven@1.4.0
  codecov: codecov/codecov@3.2.4
executors:
  docker-mongo:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/openjdk:19.0.1
      - image: mongo:6
jobs:
  build:
    executor: docker-mongo
    steps:
      - checkout
      - maven/with_cache:
          steps:
            - run: mvn -q test verify -Pcoverage
      - maven/process_test_results
      - codecov/upload:
          when: on_success
workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - build
```

See the build errors on Circle CI:  https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/hantsy/spring-reactive-jwt-sample/469/workflows/e04f6c58-1099-4821-b9c4-21ab96b22337/jobs/480

Comment: [Here's how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541). Can you please read it and apply what you learn to improve your question? For example, your title can be improved, and your error message text should be avaiable in the post without having to follow a link.

Comment: More often than not, the issue with JAVA related builds is memory exhaustion. Have you tried a bigger resource class (https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference/#docker-execution-environment). Alternatively, you could try setting memory limits (https://circleci.com/docs/java-oom/).